# java.net.SocketTimeoutException in WebService client after migration from WildFly8 / jdk8 to WildFly14 / jdk11

Tags: java, timeout, wildfly, webservice-client, java-11

Like https://docs.wildfly.org/14/Developer_Guide.html tells, I configured the timeout of my WebService client using the code below:

```
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", timeoutInMs);
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", timeoutInMs);
```

This worked fine, as long my WebService client ran on a WildFly8 using jdk8. Since I migrated it to WildFly14/jdk11 this solution does not work anymore. I tried out several Map-keys like:

```
BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT
BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT

"com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout"
"com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout"

"com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout"
"com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout"
```

Also, setting system properties "sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout" and "sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout" did not do the job.

I always get „java.net.SocketTimeoutException“ after 1 minute.
I'm about to give up.

Does anybody have any idea?

Regards, Robert

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution:

[Soap: Set TimeOut using WSDL2Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784402/soap-set-timeout-using-wsdl2java?rq=1)

So, in my example, the working code is:

```
final Client cl = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
final HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) cl.getConduit();
final HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(timeoutInMs);
httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(timeoutInMs);
httpConduit.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

All needed libraries I found in found in the modules of my WildFly14 installation:

```
system/layers/base/org/apache/cxf/impl/main/
system/layers/base/org/apache/cxf/main/
system/layers/base/javax/xml/ws/api/main/
system/layers/base/org/jboss/ws/tools/common/main/
```